# Interactive 3D plot in web browser?

Tags: plotting, export

Are there any ways to show a mathematica plot in a web browser so that the user can rotate it and such?

I am open to embedding it in a web page - or some other method such as porting it to a different language such as java or javascript.

Comment: You know about [CDF](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/), right? If you're specifically interested in 3D plots, yo should probably mention that in the title.

Comment: Actually the reason I asked about `CDF` is: if you *know* it but don't like it, I'd recommend looking into `WebGL` because that's the wave of the future. But if you're fine with `CDF`, the alternatives aren't worth the effort.

Answer (score 9):

There are several practical ways to achieve this:

- The most general way is using [CDF](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/), but this requires the user to download the CDF Player.
- There is a small and fast (works great on a Pentium 2) Java applet called [LiveGraphics3D](http://wwwvis.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/~kraus/LiveGraphics3D/) that can take `Graphics3D` objects and show them.  Unfortunately it hasn't been updated to be compatible with version 6 of Mathematica, so it'll be some trouble to make sure your `Graphics3D` doesn't have anything that it does not support.
- Finally, there's [JavaView](http://www.javaview.de), a similar but still maintained and much more feature rich program.  It supports Mathematica and makes it easy to export Mathematica graphics.

I recommend you use JavaView.

Comment: @Dror Do you use it?

Comment: It is somewhere in my background. It is indeed rather simple to export form MA and put online. Big con is that the export of MA to JavaView is limited and will not yield the same model in terms of colors, shades etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is also WebMathematica:

http://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/